# How to rename file when uploading them to server with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, form-data

I have a question about angular upload files, how I can rename files before upload? I need to give similar names to these files.
I hear about .rename method but when I try to use it, it doesn't work. 
How can I do that?

This is my Directive

```
  .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('change', function() {
            console.log('from directive', scope.$apply())
            $parse(attrs.fileModel)
                .assign(scope, element[0].files)
            scope.$apply();

        });
    }
};
```

}])

This is my Controller

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
var fd = new FormData();
angular.forEach(this.files, function(file) {

    fd.append('avatar', file);
});
$http.post('http://hannation.me/api/userplus/avatar_upload/?key=57f211a0354d7&cookie=' + $localStorage.currentUser.cookie, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }
}).success(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    AuthService.getUserGravatar().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.avatar = data;
    })
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate random number by using [Math.random();](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) and `append` the random number with file name. then store the file in a **folder** and **database** with the file  ***path***  and name for retrieve the file if you need.

Comment: Sorry i don't need random number, i need actually rename origin file before uploading.

Comment: But it will be make some  problem if you upload same file in multiple time

Comment: No way to rename file when uploading?

Comment: I thought the way is yes. but not good to do it.because Just think about . if you upload two different images with same name. What will the result. it will be override.

Comment: That why i need that) I need to override files, with same names.